# Adding a product to a Stripe charge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, stripe-payments

I know we can add the product id to a stripe charge using metadata.  Is it possible to add it directly to one of the charge attributes?

For example we can put the customer id in the `customer` attribute on the charge.

Is there a `product` attribute that we can assign the product id to?  I don't see one mentioned in the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,. a product is not a part of the charge entity in Stripe, there for there's no such field.
You can only add it to the metadata